# Vim indents css after comment block

Tags: css, vim

My CSS codes after comment block are automatically indented one class(4 spaces).

For example, in my vim, the css codes look like below:

```
.body {
    font-size: 20px;
}

/*
 * this is a comment block
 */

    .header {
        margin: 0;
    }
```

The header class is indented 4 spaces, which I want it has no indentation.

Is there a fix?

Comment: Vim is definitely not meant to indent CSS. Well, can't you use any other editor? Sorry. Just asking...

Comment: Try https://github.com/sheerun/vim-polyglot.